# Postgresql funnel data by date and state using a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery

The application has a Candidates table which monitors the activitity by date and state.
We need to query a postgresql database and return in the API on each day the number of candidates that were invited, are in progress or completed an interview (funneling).

The final SQL should return:

```
|date        |candidates  |inProgress  |completed |
|------------|------------|------------|----------| 
| 2020-10-09 |     2      |     1      |     1    |
| 2020-10-10 |     1      |     1      |     1    |
| 2020-10-11 |     1      |     0      |     0    |
```

We need a subquery to fetch and parse the entries by interview id, date.

The subquery is:

```
(select
    count(*), ca."createdAt"::date date, ca."personId",
    case
        when ca."typePhase" =-2 then 'completed'
        when ca."typePhase" =-1 then 'invited'
        else 'inProgress'
    end state
from
    public."CandidateActivity" ca
where
    ca."interviewId" = 'e639198d....'
    and ca."createdAt" between '2020-10-09 00:00:00' and '2020-10-11 23:59:59'
group by
    ca."personId", ca."typePhase", ca."createdAt"::date
order by
    ca."createdAt"::date) raw
```

We have the result for a specific state (eg: invited) if we use group by for the subquery

```
select date, count(*) as invited
from 
    (select
        count(*), ca."createdAt"::date date, ca."personId",
        case
            when ca."typePhase" =-2 then 'completed'
            when ca."typePhase" =-1 then 'invited'
            else 'inProgress'
            end state
    from
       public."CandidateActivity" ca
    where
        ca."processId" = 'e639198d....'
        and ca."createdAt" between '2020-10-09 00:00:00' and '2020-10-11 23:59:59'
    group by
       ca."personId", ca."typePhase", ca."createdAt"::date
    order by
        ca."createdAt"::date) raw
where state = 'invited'
group by date
```

Returns the correct values

```
|date      |invited |
|----------|--------|
|2020-10-09|2       |
|2020-10-10|1       |
|2020-10-11|1       |
```

How can we return using one (eficient) query all invited, in progress or completed by date?

Should be something like this:

```
select
    distinct date,
    count (*) filter (where state = 'invited') as candidates,
    count (*) filter (where state = 'inProgress') as inProgress,
    count (*) filter (where state = 'completed') as completed
from
    (
    select
        count(*), ca."createdAt"::date date, ca."personId",
        case
            when ca."typePhase" =-2 then 'completed'
            when ca."typePhase" =-1 then 'invited'
            else 'inProgress'
        end state
   from
       public."CandidateActivity" ca
   where
       ca."processId" = 'e639198d-4d20-46d8-973c-0d25a13b69d2'
       and ca."createdAt" between '2020-10-09 00:00:00' and '2020-10-11 23:59:59'
   group by
       ca."personId", ca."typePhase", ca."createdAt"::date
   order by
        ca."createdAt"::date) raw
```

We are not sure how to group by using the sql filter.

Comment: Looks to me like you just need a `GROUP BY raw.date` in the outer query. What's wrong with the last query?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was missing. Can you please add an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just directly use conditional aggreation?

```
select ca."createdAt"::date date, ca."personId",
       count(*) filter (where ca."typePhase" = -2) as completed,
       count(*) filter (where ca."typePhase" = -1) as invited,
       count(*) filter (where ca."typePhase" not in (-1, -2)) as inProgress
from public."CandidateActivity" ca
where ca."interviewId" = 'e639198d....'
group by ca."createdAt"::date
order by ca."createdAt"::date;
```